# TypeScript Specify Value Type But Not Key Type of Map

Tags: typescript, dictionary, types

I want to enforce a generic typing on a map such that every value of every key is a specific type (in this example `A`), but I do not want to override the underlying default key type. In the example below, if I specify the type of `MY_MAP` to be `Record<string, A>`, the `MyMapKeys` type changes from the desired key union `'unknown' | 'error'` to `string`. How can I preserve the readonly keys of `MY_MAP` while also enforcing the map's generic value type to be `A`?:

```js
type A = {
  name: string;
  description: string;
};

// MY_MAP must be a map of readonly string keys and type A values
const MY_MAP = {
  unknown: {
    name: 'unknown',
    description: 'unknown',
  },
  error: {
    name: 'error',
    // should display error: missing property "description"
  },
} as const;

// I want the following to be 'unknown' | 'error' not string
type MyMapKeys = keyof typeof MY_MAP;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Typescript 4.9 (currently in beta as of Oct 5, 2022)

There is a new feature for this called [the `satisfies` operator.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#hamilton)

This allows you declare a value that is constrained to a type, and can be inferred to be a more specific type.

```
const MY_MAP = {
  unknown: {
    name: 'unknown',
    description: 'unknown',
  },
  error: {
    name: 'error',
  },
} as const satisfies Record<string, A>;
// Type '{ readonly unknown: { readonly name: "unknown"; readonly description: "unknown"; }; readonly error: { readonly name: "error"; }; }' does not satisfy the expected type 'Record<string, A>'.
//  Property 'error' is incompatible with index signature.
//    Property 'description' is missing in type '{ readonly name: "error"; }' but required in type 'A'.(1360)
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.9.0-dev.20221005#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFKA7AhgWwgC4oBnYAJwEssBzAbnUwBMISBjKsYSgey2LJVaDNAF8R6APSSoAWQCaAfVkwAClDwBXMlABG0HBpxgoPAGZRyEHEz4AbEKQrUaUANYQQJKDixMooJCwUABuOHaarOhsfDoKymoIyIxQmlhuWDwA7vzJGJjY+ERQAORpGdlYJQA0KcysHJRcvLll6Zk5NSmitfkQ5OQ85MSo+Zi4BMQl-YPkXWNQ0qQAFjyadv5MlCRgdjiOM0PEeNskLlBgg5DkoFAARCzsnNx8d929oj7eMVg6JDjcEhmSisKAAJQgMXITAAPIIXNVYAA+CRoJYASSgWV8wACy2gZh4djs2XOwB4emgbQqnSgAB9Soc5tgeLj4bR0IFoLIQLJjABpTzeRAeEDmALgCDi+IqVR0IA)

---

#### In Typescript 4.8 or lower

The work around for this has always been to use a generic identity function.

```
function makeMap<T extends Record<string, A>>(map: T): T {
  return map
}

// MY_MAP must be a map of readonly string keys and type A values
const MY_MAP = makeMap({
  unknown: {
    name: 'unknown',
    description: 'unknown',
  },
  error: {
    // Property 'description' is missing in type '{ name: string; }' but required in type 'A'.(2741)
    name: 'error',
  },
});
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFKA7AhgWwgC4oBnYAJwEssBzAbnUwBMISBjKsYSgey2LJVaDNAF8R6AGYBXLG258oeHAGsIAWRxgAPABUoEAB7AIWJiSgAlCGx7km2wdRoAaWAD53ACmVhiugEp-ZEYocghgaXIsJS10UXR0AHokqHUATQB9dRgABSVpMigAI2gcWLAoHkkwiBwmPgAbEFIKZyg1EAscMyhQSFgoADccRulWdFssIozsvIRYtU0wL1QMKFkVLB4Ad34Q9cxcAmIAck3tvdOXUOZWDkouXn3zrC3drGvQ0Rv1iHJyHZiGtMJgUlBcoDIORQFBTix2JwFJ8oJQLHg0SR2tQ+uBoKckNh8ERWkJ6FBRKcStJgLUAI7SSjhJiomL9fEwU4AOi8ACYAOwAFgAjAFbkSTnD-oDyF91j94gEJGhwQBJKA7Hq04AAC2gkh4jUau3awB4JXxFw+VIAPlKAXYqdtaU5aOh2WkQMsANIQLoLTrVXGQIOzHK5OhAA)

Comment: When you fix the type error, the keys can then be inferred correctly.  See https://tsplay.dev/WGAzJN. You can also add `as const` to the end of the object literal that you pass to the function if you need that.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It puts a requirement on the value types, but does not specify them. If `description` field was optional in `A`, your first example would compile, but `MY_MAP[key].description` would result in an error.